# Бэкап базы postgres для пользователя приложения

Tags: java, postgresql

У приложения есть множество пользователей, которые постоянно что-то пишут в базу postgresql. Как реализовать бэкап данных для каждого отдельного пользователя с возможностью отката например на неделю? Может есть какие-то готовые решения?

Comment: А пишут то они в одну бд? или хотябы в разные таблицы?

Comment: Пишут в одну дб с множеством таблиц. Как обычно, у каждого свой id, по которому связаны таблицы к конкретному пользователю.